# E-mail Communication

Tags: email, jms, jakarta-mail

How to get total email conversation with single common identifier in all email messages using java. javaMail API and JMS is giving sender and receiver message id which is different. I need the common identifer which will specify the communication thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing.  If you're trying to correlate messages into a "thread" or "conversation", see [this](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html).